# Submit button in Safari browser appears only partly

Tags: html, css, safari

What's wrong with my submit button in Safari? It's placed into a container with "display:table-cell" and appears only partly as you can see in the attached image. If I place it between `<p></p>` tags, everything works fine. Is there another solution?

The problem is caused by `display:table-cell.` If I remove `display:table-cell`, the problem disappears. Why?

```css
.submit_button{

    color:#fff;
    background:#80AA28;
    border:solid 1px #729823;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding:8px 15px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;
    -moz-background-clip:padding;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="submit_button" />

<p><input type="submit" class="submit_button" /><p>

<p style="display:table-cell"><input type="submit" class="submit_button" /><p>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNBim.jpg)

Comment: I just converted your code to a snippet and am running safari - I'm not seeing the issue at all, so the code posted in probably not related to your issue. You need to post a more complete code that replicates the issue your are having.

Comment: @somethinghere Stupid question, but have you tried putting the button in a table? The OP says that's when the problem occurs. I don't have Safari, so I can't try.

Comment: @MrListed I just added a `p display:table-cell` to his code and yes, it looks exactly the same. All three look exactly the same. Thre must be more code making this issue occur.

Comment: Yes, @MrListed, its because of table-cell. I already edited my post.

Comment: But do you have the same problem in the snippet here? @somethinghere doesn't. Are the two of you using the same version of Safari?

Comment: @MrListed I am on Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6) - but even then, I feel there is more CSS code missing here. He never shows the code that defines the `display: table-cell`, so we can't be sure of other properties potentially interfering here. So Verode, please add more code so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was caused by:

```
table {
height:100%;
}
```